# Assertions.assertIterableEquals not recognize actually equal objects

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit

I have a test which fails with `Assertions.assertIterableEquals(expected, result)` but object actually is equals:

```
@Test
public void whenArticleWrittenByAuthorOrWithTitleIsExistThenReturnArticleList() {
    // given
    List<Article> expected = articleRepository.saveAll(List.of(article));

    // when
    List<Article> result = articleRepository.findByAuthorOrTitle(author, article.getTitle());

    // then
    Assertions.assertIterableEquals(expected, result);
}
```

Which fails with the message:

```
iterable contents differ at index [0], expected: com.pravvich.model.Article@47d7e8b5
<Article(id=1, author=Author(name=name, login=login), title=title, content=content, tags=[tag])> 
but was: com.pravvich.model.Article@4353230
<Article(id=1, author=Author(name=name, login=login), title=title, content=content, tags=[tag])>
```

Why it can happen and how to fix it?

Article object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private Author author;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;

    private String content;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @CollectionTable(name = "tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")
    )
    @Column(name = "tag")
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Article article = (Article) o;

        if (!Objects.equals(id, article.id)) return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(author, article.author)) return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(title, article.title)) return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(content, article.content)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(tags, article.tags);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (author != null ? author.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (content != null ? content.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (tags != null ? tags.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Author {

    private String name;

    private String login;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Author author = (Author) o;

        if (!Objects.equals(name, author.name)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(login, author.login);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (login != null ? login.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE_1**

Problem in `tags` collection. `assertIterableEquals` apply collection approach only for `List<Article>` but for `List<String> tags` still use standart `equals` method. Question more about how to apply equals for nested collections?

**UPDATE_2**

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.pravvich'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository
        extends JpaRepository<Article, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Article> {

    @Query("SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.author = :author")
    List<Article> findAllWrittenBy(Author author);

    @Query("SELECT t FROM Article a JOIN a.tags t WHERE a.title = :title")
    List<String> findAllTagsOfArticle(String title);

    @Query("SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.author = :author OR a.title = :title")
    List<Article> findByAuthorOrTitle(Author author, String title);

    @Query("SELECT a.author FROM Article a WHERE a.title = :title")
    Optional<Author> findAuthorOfArticleByTitle(String title);
}
```

Comment: Has `Author` an implemented `equals()` method?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the problem you have. The code looks fine, so there must be something else in your program. Also add the tools and libraries you are using to your question and adjust the tags list of the question as well.

Comment: @Timo yes `Author` class in question

Comment: @Pavel I suspect the problem is the `tags` collection as well, but the `equals()` method for `List<>` is already well defined that it returns `true` when the content is the same. The issue might be somewhere else. Please [edit] your question to include the MCVE.

Comment: @Progman I didn't catch what do you miss for completion MCVE.

Comment: @Pavel The list of libraries you are using (in which versions), the configurations of the libraries you are using, the full JUnit test suite so we can see any configuration relevant information. You are also using a service `articleRepository` we don't see the implementation of, but it might not be relevant to the problem you have. Do you get the same problem when you create the `Article` and `Author` objects manually? Again, the `equals()` implementation looks fine, so the issue is somewhere else (like a framework creating proxies on the way that override `equals()`).

Comment: @Progman add build.gradle

Comment: Hi Pavel!
As you already found out, the problem is the tag list. I took a deeper look: The tag list is of type `PersistentBag` and uses the `equals()` Method of Object. Instead of using `Objects.equals(tags, article.tags)` you can pick a solution from here: [How to work with Hibernate's PersistentBag not obeying List equals contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399383/12165732)